# Why does this always return, found even when it shouldn't?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Im checking to see if the user exist in the db before allowing it to go further into the onboarding process. No matter what email I try it says email found, why?
What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
    var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func signUp(email: String, password: String) {
    let doesEmailExist = db.collection("users").document(email)
    
    doesEmailExist.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
            if document.exists {
                print("email found")
            } else {
                print("email is new")
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger?  Set a breakpoint on the `if let` line and examine `document` - What is it?

Comment: What is the guy that you so-call 'the db'?  Which one are you referring to with the Firebase tag?  Firebase has several different services.

Comment: var db = Firestore.firestore()

Comment: First, when I run the code, it says "email is new". Second thing - and this is important, using email addresses as documentId's is going to cause you a headache down the road. There are certain restrictions on documentId's and they cannot be changed. So if a user updates their email in the future, you're going to have to parse your entire database and read in, delete, and write out that data. Lots of extra work. You should also include error checking to handle any errors that are returned - they can be quite revealing (hint hint)